# Javascript/DOM Why is does my form not support submit()?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, dom

This is my first time working with asp.net and javascript, so I don't know a lot of the nice web resources, or much about debugging javascript. I'm looking to find out why on line 
`oFormObject.submit();` Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

I'm using links to function as buttons because I'm terrible at aesthetics and I think links will look more professional than a table of 50 buttons. I read that this solution may cause issues with browsers trying to pre-render my links and causing lots of extra traffic and problems, but the Css I found to make a button look like a link seemed to have alignment and spacing issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DefectSeverity.css" /><title>
  Defect Severity Assessment Code List
</title></head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="CodeList.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjQzMTI3NjU4ZGSW2wNBW3eGztyO+Tftc5BB8A6cMg==" />
</div>

<div>
<p>Welcome Maslow</p><SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function submitForm(intId)
{ oFormObject= document.getElementById(""form"+_StrCodeId + @""");
oFormElement= document.getElementById("codeId");
oFormElement.value=intId;
  oFormObject.submit();
}
</SCRIPT> <form method="post" action="CodeAssessment.aspx" id="formcodeId">
<table name="codeId" id="codeId" value="0" type="hidden" class="linkTable">
<tr>
   <th>Completed</th><th>Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Code Present Since</th>
</tr><tr class="row">
<td><input name="401" type="checkbox" value="401" DISABLED /></td><td><a href="javascript:submitForm(0);">401</a></td><td>Missing Original Document/form</td><td>2009.10.16</td>
</tr><tr class="rowAlternate">
<td><input name="NDMI" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="NDMI" DISABLED /></td>
<td><a href="javascript:submitForm(1);">NDMI</a></td>
<td>Note date is missing</td>    <td>2009.10.15</td>
</tr>
 </table><input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the script line to `oFormObject= document.forms[0];` it submits the asp.net's viewstate form posting back to the same page instead of where I want to go. so the rest of the code on the page appears to work.

Comment: are you saying if you change the line oFormObject= document.getElementById(""form"+_StrCodeId + @"""); TO oFormObject= document.forms[0];  The form submits fine?

Comment: it submitted but it submitted the other form. The one asp.net put in by default on the web form template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we solved this in another answer, but using comments, so this is just incase anyone else has the same problem,

It's all down to the form having a runat="server" attribute, this generates the viewstate input, then when the form is submitted to the second page, it tries to fill out the page with the details from the viewstate, however as in this case the form is submitted to another page, the two pages don't match up and when it tries to deal with the viewstate input it throws the error.

The solution is to either remove the runat="server" attribute on the form, or to set EnableViewStateMac="False" attribute from the second page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into asp.net but into javascript, so I'd say there's a parse error in

```
oFormObject= document.getElementById(""form"+_StrCodeId + @""");
```

the quotes just don't match. i'd say you try to change it to

```
oFormObject= document.getElementById("formcodeId");
```

instead

Comment: sorry that code is in my asp. so the extra `"` are needed to pass it out as the proper javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently you can't nest forms in html/DOM. I have changed my asp.net provided form and now it navigates but crashes saying

`Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DefectSeverity.css" /><title>
 Defect Severity Assessment Code List
</title></head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="CodeAssessment.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjQzMTI3NjU4ZGSW2wNBW3eGztyO+Tftc5BB8A6cMg==" />
</div>

<div>
<p>Welcome Maslow</p><SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function submitForm(intId)
{ oFormObject= document.forms[0];
oFormElement= document.getElementById("codeId");
oFormElement.value=intId;
oFormObject.submit();
}

</SCRIPT> <table name="codeId" id="codeId" value="0" type="hidden" class="linkTable">
<tr>
    <th>Completed</th><th>Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Code Present Since</th>
</tr><tr class="row">
    <td><input name="401" type="checkbox" value="401" DISABLED /></td>
<td><a href="javascript:submitForm(0);">401</a></td><td>Missing Original Document/form</td><td>2009.10.16</td>

</tr><tr class="rowAlternate">
    <td><input name="NDMI" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="NDMI" DISABLED /></td>
<td><a href="javascript:submitForm(1);">NDMI</a></td><td>Note date is missing</td><td>2009.10.15</td>
</tr>
</table><input id="testSubmit" type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How come you've got your JS mid div? Why not put it in the head tags?

Comment: moved it to the head section. no improvement.

Comment: no I know there wouldn't be, thats just more a general comment, I just prefer my code to be in head whereever possible thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the issue is now, the code you posted in your answer worked fine for me, only problem I have is that I dont have a CodeAssesment.aspx page so I get a HTML404 error, but thats it.
Your original code document.getElementById(""form"+_StrCodeId + @"""); was not valid, and you don't have a variable called StrCodeId,

Try

```
oFormObject = document.getElementById("form"+intId);
```

Comment: try making a blank CodeAssessment.aspx page to recieve the post. `document.getElementById(""form"+_StrCodeId + @""");` is valid in the .aspx.cs file where it resides. private const string _StrCodeId = "codeId";

Comment: oh, so you have some CS writing that bit of the page aswell?

Comment: @Psytronic - right, CS is writing that section so that if I need to change the element name, I change it in one place and everywhere else automatically updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved the crashing, so I put another answer, its because you've copied the source code and used that to create the outline again, I think, as you shouldn't have the hidden input viewstate as part of the page, it gets generated automatically on build. Remove this line and try it

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjQzMTI3NjU4ZGSW2wNBW3eGztyO+Tftc5BB8A6cMg==" />
</div>
```

Comment: so you were able to reproduce the crash?

Comment: yeah, Even if it was a bog standard white page it would produce that error, and then removing that input (and subsquent superfolous div) made it go through fine.

I should point out that your page isn't valid with the DOCType you've declared, you might want to look into that

Comment: yeah while you have been trying to figure it out, I've been running through http://validator.w3.org/ to clean it up, and see if that helps. but I don't have an extra <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" in my aspx or .cs.

Comment: the page it is posting to is basically a blank aspx template page.

Comment: Hmmm, ok maybe that was jsut a coincidence with the input then, as it works now when I put it in, it could be to do with the attributes, if you are using VisWebExpress it should highlight them for you. If not the main ones will be the table being hidden and having a value, remove those and try

Comment: The entire table is being dynamically generated via C#. I'm in VS2008 professional. I've now cut out the entire table and I'm still getting the error, posting another answer with the html.

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed out my dynamic code generation section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DefectSeverity.css" /><title>
 Defect Severity Assessment Code List
</title><script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(intId)
{ oFormObject= document.forms[0];
oFormElement= document.getElementById("codeId");
oFormElement.value=intId;
  oFormObject.submit();
}
</script> </head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="CodeAssessment.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMzMxMzk5NjY5ZGTQg8pLRPHaRM4Idd6LyKDmFvMpNA==" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey look there's another div again. I don't see where this is coming from. and I'm still getting Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: I noticed that there's now no element called codeId. putting one in didn't solve the problem.

Comment: bascially that div contains the values of the input elements on the page, so if the page submits to itself you don't have to tell it to display the values from before.

Comment: are you using <asp: input> tags?

Comment: But I bet your form still has the runat="server" tag? :p

Comment: That is what is creating the viewstate, what are you planning on doing with the data from the form on the second page?

Comment: Because bascically if you are dealing with it on another page then I don't think you need that tag, as that only deals with post backs (ie form submitting to itself) if say you want a button to change some text on the page (and dont want to use javascript)

Comment: I had no idea what that tag was for. but since it gave it to me by default I assumed it needed to be there for something. removing the runat=server for the form made it work. a work around was to change the recieving page to say EnableViewStateMac="False" in the <%@ Page section. post all this as an answer so I can give you credit. =)